# python `traceback` production performance

Tags: python, django, traceback

I'm using try catch blocks to handle exceptions in my Django app. However, I'm also using `traceback` module to print debug information in case an exception is caught.

```
try:
   # Exception gets thrown here
except:
   traceback.print_exc()
```

Should I remove this when moving into production? Does this have significant performance consequences (like xdebug in PHP, for instance)?

Comment: I would recommend to use logging and the `exception()`-Method of the logger instead of `traceback.print_exc()`.

Comment: Because the debug level of `logging` is the usual way of logging debugging information. And Django uses/recommends the `logging` module of Python. You can control what happens the the output, if it happens at all, and have additional information like the name of the logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no significant performance implications to this; the traceback is already present with the exception when it is raised.

All `traceback.print_exc()` does is *print* the information already there.

Comment: The information is there but not formatted as a traceback. If this slows down the program depends on the amount/rate of tracebacks printed I guess.

Comment: Also is there any performance concern when using: traceback.format_stack()